# Can you run WebBrowser under a WCF service?

Tags: c#, wcf, browser

I'm currently trying to move over a screen-scraping program (c# forms application) to a WCF service.

The screen-scraping program uses **WebBrowser** to grab info off several pages for which there is no API. I would like to know if you can run **WebBrowser** in a service let alone a form. I'm currently developing on XP to be release on Server 2003.

Currently when running unit test, I can only see the **WebBrowser** if it was made on the "Unit Test" side and even then I need to manually pop up **MessageBox**'es to get **WebBrowser** to stop from not navigating with a blank screen.

The program is being moved and split up since we are having multi-threading issues.

Comment: what you describe (i.e. running IE in a Windows Service) is basically NOT supported for several reasons, among other reasons for example security issues... IF you really want to do this from a Windows Service use a "headless" browser engine... if that is an option I can provide some links etc.

Comment: IE engine is not designed to be run as service - please don't. Also if the reason is "having multi-threading issues" it is highly unlikely to have less of them by making it a service that start more threads at the same time easier than desktop app...

Comment: Yahia - I am trying to do something similar related to screen scraping info off websites to be returned via web service. If you have any experience with headless browsers could you recommend one?

Comment: This may be a stupid question: why aren't you rather using something like the `WebClient` class?

Comment: @EbenRoux: probably because, in a Windows Forms application, the WebBrowser control does better with handling script and such, since it really _is_ IE.

Comment: @John Saunders: Ah! I guess that is a good a reason as any.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would be better off using a headless browser like Phantom.js: http://www.phantomjs.org/. It offers significant features and has no problem being executed wherever you need like a regular command - line program.

Answer (score 1):

In thinking about this, realize that each instance of the WebBrowser control is actually an instance of Internet Explorer. Your question then becomes one of having a service start multiple instances of Internet Explorer.

But Internet Explorer is an interactive application. It expects to control the keyboard and mouse when it has the focus.

- *Which keyboard and mouse do you want it to control when running in the server?*
- *How many keyboards and mice does your server  have?*

You could find some way for the service to launch a Remote Desktop connection and start up your Windows Forms application. You could then have your Windows Forms application host a WCF service, and the two services could talk to each other. I have seen this sort of thing done when it was necessary to automate a specialized interactive program which could not be made into a service.